# How to compare a variable to a core data attribute?

Tags: xcode, core-data, attributes

I have an NSString userSelection that is set to the name of the user selected in the application. When a user creates a new instance of the entity, an attribute "user" is set to the name of the current user. What I want is to be able to check if userSelection == user. Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Core Data attribute (user) is also an NSString, then a simple comparison should do the trick:

```
if ([userSelection isEqualToString:yourAttribute]) {
    // it's the same user
} else {
    // not the same user
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response. To be able to reference the attribute like that in the code, do I need to import the data model somehow?

Comment: No, just access your attributes the usual way via a fetch request. If you have a managed object subclass setup you can compare it right away, otherwise typecast yourAttribute to an NSString.